# Need Sorting With External Array or Comma Separated data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.0

Am working with PostgreSQL 8.0.2, I have table

```
create table rate_date (id serial, rate_name text);
```

and it's data is

```
 id  rate_name
 --------------
 1   startRate
 2   MidRate
 3   xlRate
 4   xxlRate
```

After select it will show data with default order or order by applied to any column of same table. My requirement is I have separate entity from where I will get data as (xlRate, MidRate,startRate,xxlRate) so I want to use this data to sort the select on table rate_data. I have tried for values join but it's not working and no other solution am able to think will work. If any one have idea please share detail.

Output should be

```
xlRate
MidRate
startRate
xxlRate
```

my attempt/thinking.

```
select id, rate_name 
from rate_date r
join (
  VALUES (1, 'xlRate'),(2, 'MidRate')
) as x(a,b) on x.b = c.rate_name
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  In addition, you should upgrade the version of Postgres.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff Thanks, version update is not possible, sample I added table with 2 columns id and rate_name.

Comment: Postgres 8.0 is long dead and forgotten you shouldn't be using that any more

Comment: You'd have to add some `CREATE TABLE` statements and your attempt so that we know what you are talking about. Besides, upgrade. It is possible (and may save your database).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is helpful but in Oracle you could achieve that this way:

```
select *
from
(
select id, rate_name,
case rate_name
    when 'xlRate' then 1
    when 'MidRate' then 2
    when 'startRate' then 3
    when 'xxlRate' then 4
    else 100
end my_order    
from rate_date r
)
order by my_order
```

May be you can do something like this in PostgreSQL?